# How to display database on web framework?

Tags: python, flask

I want to display the content of the database from .db file on web framework using flask module. However, only the row title is able to be displayed on the web framework. The content of the database from the .db file couldn't load out on the web framework. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks. 
This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

def connect_db(db):
    con = sqlite3.connect(db) 
    return  con.cursor()

@app.route('/') 
def index():    
    db ='mcu_aurix_git.db'
    cur = connect_db(db)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mcu_aurix")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('flask.html', rows=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

flask.html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>project</th>
        <th>branch</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>subject</th>
        <th>owner_name</th>
        <th>owner_email</th>
        <th>owner_username</th>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>commitMessage</th>
        <th>createdOn</th>
        <th>lastUpdated</th>
        <th>open</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>current_date</th>          
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{row.project_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.branch_id}}</td>
                <td>{{row.id_id}}</td>
                <td>{{row.num_number}}</td>
                <td>{{row.subject_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.owner_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.owner_email}}</td>
                <td>{{row.owner_username}}</td>
                <td>{{row.url_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.commitMessage_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.num_createdOn}}</td>
                <td>{{row.num_lastUpdated}}</td>
                <td>{{row.num_open}}</td>
                <td>{{row.status_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.current_date}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there anything missing in my code? Hopefully anyone can help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `rows` variable to the html page.

```
return render_template('flask.html', data=data)
```

You are only passing `data` variable.

If you want to use `rows` inside your html page, you need to use

```
return render_template('flask.html', rows=data)
```

Also one more thing,

```
{{row.project_name}}
```

You cannot get the value of `project_name` like this, you need to use index value (col. no. starting from 0). Like,

```
{{row[0]}}
```

Instead of manually creating `<td>` for each col value, you can just use the below `tbody` code.

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            {% for col in row %}
                <td> {{ col }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That means I only need to use this tbody code instead of manually creating all the <td> value?

Comment: @NICK It will populate the `<td>` tags according to the no. of col values present in `row`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Codelt! It's work! By the way, the result displayed on the web framework is a bit messy. How can I do if I want the result is in table form just look like in a Excel file? Thanks

Comment: Start investigating Bootstrap and JavaScript UI frameworks.

Comment: Hi @Codelt, can u Ping me again? I didn't find your PING chat already, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @Codelt, I want to ask you some thing about my code. Can you send me the chat room again? I think it's better to have our discussion in the chat room. Thanks.